# how can do slices in python similar to slices in praraview?

Tags: python, 3d, paraview

For those who are familiar with paraview: in 3D case we can do slice and contour and visualize for example what it inside a sphere/cylinder/box.
I am wondering if there is any tool to do the same things in python? I mean if rather than reading a file in preview, I will read it in python, and obtain a 3D plot, which tool can I use to get slices and contours  in python plot similar to those in praview?

Answer (score 0):

ParaView is also available through a python module, so what you do in the graphical interface is also doable in python.

See this [introduction](https://docs.paraview.org/en/latest/UsersGuide/introduction.html#getting-started-with-pvpython).